# How to add a layer for the ocean from imported 'bil' files

Tags: qgis

I am very new to QGIS. I downloaded data from earth explorer for east of florida. I am trying to create a decent landscape for my flight simulator "Condor" as I am a glider pilot. So, I merged the bil file, then warped it and then clipped it. I added various vector layers from QuickOSM. I downloaded the water from the Earth Explorer site and added the layer. But it doesn't show up when I deselect the clipped layer. I attached 2 pics, one of the clipped and the other without it. The one with the clipped layer has a black line that's the coast. And the other is the intercoastal water way. How do I add the small portion in the clipped for the ocean? Clipped view of bil file[image: clipped]

Comment: Please add some screenshots showing your problem(s), as they would really readers visualize what is going on.

Comment: ... really help readers ...

Comment: I tried to attach a jpeg

Comment: What kind of data is "the water from the Earth Explorer site"? A screenshot of your Layers panel would be helpful.